# Java Access an Array in an object

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I have a method (validateaddress) that returns a HashMap to another method (validateapplicant).

"validateaddress" returns `{success=false, payload=[]}` to "validateapplicant"

How do I access the first index within the `validateaddress(property).get("payload")` array

```
public void validateapplicant(application application){

   propertymodel property = new propertymodel();

   property.setStreet1(application.getApplicant().getStreet1());
   property.setStreet2(application.getApplicant().getStreet2());

   HashMap<String,Object> validation = validateaddress(property).get("payload");
 
   ^^^ How to make validation equal the first index? ^^^
   
}

public HashMap<String, Object> validateaddress(propertymodel property){
    
    propertymodel suggestion = new propertymodel();

    suggestion.setStreet1("Some Street");

    ArrayList<propertymodel> payload = new ArrayList<propertymodel>();

    payload.add(suggestion);

    HashMap<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();

    response.put("success", false);
    response.put("payload", payload);

    return response;
}
```

Comment: What about just casting it like `((ArrayList<propertymodel>)(validateaddress(property).get("payload"))`? But anyways, why are you retzrning a `Map` instead of a class for this?

Comment: While casting works in your case, a `HashMap` is just not made for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing the first index you must have to cast the "*validateaddress(property).get("payload")*" into an ArrayList first.

```
((ArrayList<propertymodel>) validateaddress(property).get("payload")).get(0)
```

should do the trick.

Otherwise, you can also take the validation value from validateAddress function in the object of type HashMap<String,ArrayList>, through which you won't require the casting part, we had to do above.

Comment: Casting to `HashMap<String,ArrayList>` would be wrong as the value of the `Map` is not always an `ArrayList`. Also, you should not use raw types.

Comment: But this is true for this case, right? I don't think you'll get any issues doing that. But still, if you want to be extra cautious, you can use List instead.

Comment: It is true for this case. The `HashMap` contains a boolean value for the key `"success"`.

Comment: If you only have ArrayList when you have payload as "success" you can do a conditional handling for same, and it will work fine. Just write an if condition, 

If(validateaddress(property).get("payload").equals("success")){
    // casting code
}

Comment: Take a look at the question. There is **another** entry in the `Map` where the key is `success` and the value is a boolean.

Comment: A minor tweak to the if clause. If(validateaddress(property).get("success")){ // casting code }

Comment: This is not what I meant. I meant that it shouldn't be cast to `HashMap<String,ArrayList>`.

Comment: Well in that case,  the already provided "casting to ArrayList<propertymodel>" is still there. You can utilize this along with the condition provided in above comment.

Comment: Yes but even though casting to `HashMap<String,ArrayList>`, it would be wrong because of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your 'Object' is of type ArrayList why not declare the map as `HashMap<String, ArrayList>`?

In terms of retrieving the first index of the ArrayList Object you can do something like that

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList> validation = validateaddress(property);
for(Entry<String, ArrayList> list : validation.entrySet()) {
    list.getValue().get(0); // return 1st index
}
```

**EDIT**: As rightly pointed out, by dan1st, you do have boolean as well. In that case you can do something like

```
for (Entry<String, Object> arr : list.entrySet()) {
    try {
        String value = ((ArrayList<String>) arr.getValue()).get(0);
        System.out.println(value);
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        System.out.println("not array");
    }
}
```

For simplicity, I've used the String object in the ArrayList. btw: propertymodel should be capitalized since its a class

Comment: Because the list also contains a `Boolean` value. Also, you should not use raw generic types.

Comment: You could just use `instanceof` instead of waiting for a `ClassCastException`. However, note that generics are not present at runtime and the cast would still be unchecked (same with the try-catch). Also, why would you iterate over all values of the `Map` when you just need the value of the key `payload`?

Comment: @dan1st yes - you could also use instanceof, however try-catch is more 'cost effective' as far as JVM is concerned. Is it the best approach? One could argue. As far as I understand OP wants to access the first index in each array. And if that's the case you have to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

`validateaddress()` returns a `HashMap<String, Object>` where `success` points to a `Boolean` and `payload` points to an `ArrayList<propertymodel>`.

If you use `validateaddress(property).get("payload")`, the compiler sees that this returns an `Object` and does not know what type of object this is.

### The dirty approach

You can cast it to an `ArrayList<propertymodel>` like this:

```
ArrayList<propertymodel> model=((ArrayList<propertymodel>)validateaddress(property).get("payload"))
```

However, this is not a safe approach and the compiler will even tell you that this is an unchecked cast.

The problem with this is that it something that is something that the `Object` could be something that is not a `ArrayList<propertymodel>` if you make a mistake and the compiler has no possibility to spot such mistake.

Instead, you should use object oriented programming or exceptions.

### use OOP for better type safety

Instead of making a `HashMap` where the values consist of multiple types, you can make a class where different attributes have different types:

```java
public class AddressValidationResult{
    private final boolean success;
    private final ArrayList<propertymodel> payload;
    public AddressValidationResult(boolean success,ArrayList<propertymodel> payload){
        this.success=success;
        this.payload=payload;  
    }
    public boolean isSuccessfull(){
        return success;
    }
    public ArrayList<propertymodel> getPayload(){
        return payload;
    }
}
```

You can then return an instance of this class and use the getters in order to safely retrieve the data.

This would be a way to fix your problem without messing up type safety.

```java
public AddressValidationResult validateaddress(propertymodel property){
    
    propertymodel suggestion = new propertymodel();

    suggestion.setStreet1("Some Street");

    ArrayList<propertymodel> payload = new ArrayList<propertymodel>();

    payload.add(suggestion);

    return new AddressValidationResult(false,payload);
}
```

After that, you can access it safely using `validateaddress(property).getPayload()`

### Exceptions

The `HashMap` only contains of a success variable and the `payload` containing the actual data.

Instead of returning such a `Map`, you could just return the actual data and throw an exception if the validation failed.

However, this might not work out for you as you would not have the `payload` if the validation failed.